# Unable to redirect to error page in blazor server as it is returning 200 status code to the page that does not exists

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-5, blazor-routing

In Blazor, we can directly assign the route to each page on the razor itself. (that's the fun part doing) but I want to navigate to "/error" or "/404" page when any non-existing url is entered. Please Help me how we can get 404 status and implement the redirection. as it is an important task for SEO purpose.

ive tried many solutions: 1: i have created a component "error.razor"  and  added that component in app.razor inside the **notfound** section. in this scenario i am **getting a 200 status code with same non-existing url** in address bar
2: for a forceful redirection, i have injected NavigationManager in the "error.razor", with the help of NavigationManager i am redirecting it to 404 page. and i.e. a 302 redirection.

**Edit:** I am trying to get 400 status code on non-existing page. but i am getting 200. how can i get proper 400 error status in network panel. Help me on that.

FYR :
[Correct url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb3rg.jpg)

[Damaged Url/Non Existing URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRMB5.jpg)

help me out if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom `NotFoundPage` component that will display what you want the user to see when they navigate to a page that does not exist and put it under NotFound Context in `app.razor`

```
<Router>
    <NotFound>
        <CascadingAuthenticationState>
            <NotFoundPage></NotFoundPage> 
        </CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <NotFound>
</Router>
```

Comment: Hi Qudus,
May be i was not clear with my question. I have edited the question. please check the image i have uploaded for the reference. i am getting 200 status code on non-existing url ,but it should be 404 .